# views alter query

Tags: views

I have content type `event` that has `date` field
and i created view "events" to this content type and added contextual filter "Date".

The problem is in the database the field date value is stored with this format
`2007-01-17T00:00:00`
and I want to filter like this `events/2007`.  Unfortunately, I get no results because the URL should be like this `events/2007-01-17T00:00:00`.

So what is the solution for making it work with this `events/2007` by altering 
the query using `views_views_query_alter()` instead of creating field that hold the value like this `2007`. I believe that altering the query by this way should solve it but it didn't

```
function views_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'events' && is_numeric(arg(1)) ) {
    $view->query->where[0]['conditions'][3]['field']=" YEAR('field_data_field_date.field_date_value')";    
  }
}
```

Comment: Mohamad, the edit was to improve the readability of the question, which in turn will get you a better answer. Formatted as-is, some people won't even bother reading the question or will edit it

Comment: hello mohamad salama, also I suggest to try to give format your question, for example for your code. is just add some spaces before each line in your code.

Comment: Mohamad, remember to use functions to test/debug your functions, for example, if you have Devel module, you can use **dsm()** to output values that are you working (or you can use the very helpful **print_r** or the **echo**).

Comment: i already debug the query & the results 
and when i add 'YEAR' sql function to the field 
'field_date_value' by doing so
 $view->query->where[0]['conditions'][3]['field']=" YEAR('field_data_field_date.field_date_value')";
it doing something wrong to the query 
is gota be some way else for doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Which Drupal and Views versions? From what I can see on my test site when creating:

A Filter Criteria you can specify granularity to year; same thing goes for a Contextual filter. (D7, latest Views).

Comment: yes its D 7.7 & View 7.x-3.0
all i want to do something that hook the criteria field
to make it YEAR('field_date_value') instead of just 'field_date_value3'